# Reading Data from XML and writing it to Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

According to requirement, there will be some XML files (about 20-30) using which I have to read them and insert the details in Database. 
My application is using EF4.0 with oracle.

I would like to know the best possible way to read the XML and insert the records in database.

What i am thinking is, to load the XML data into Dataset and then save them one by one using EF only.

If anyone can suggest me some better and efficient way to achieve it, then it would be really helpful.

Whether loading data from XML to dataset and then from Dataset to Entity is a better approach or by using LINQ to XML, directly create the Entity object while reading the XML?

Comment: what size xml files?  For what its worth, I've had good success going the xml->dataset route (with xsd), but must be reasonable sized files (say 50Mb max)

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate XSD for your XML files   http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html
2. Generate C# classes from your XSD  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx
3. Serialise your XML into your model.
4. work with data however you wish

This is how I  work with XML

Comment: I had never worked with this, so is it possible for you to provide me some link or u can describe as well using which I can try with it.